# Cannot create shortcut of .exe on windows 8->create on desktop instead->disk space full

Tags: windows, shortcuts

Just now I noticed I can not create shortcuts of `.exe` files.

I already tried:

- right click create shortcut
- send to desktop (create shortcut)
- right click->new shortcut

In all situations I get an error:

> couldn't create shortcut here, want to create it on desktop instead?

After clicking yes I get an error:

> disk space full, could not create shortcut

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Is your disk actually full?

Comment: Sounds like Windows _newspeak_: maybe write permission is denied **or** [the disk quota policy in Windows 8 is enabled](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/enforce-disk-quota-limit-windows) and the limit is exceeded **or** alike…

Comment: no, disk is not full. approx 300 gb left of 500 gb and no disk quota limit set.

Comment: Try this: Press Windows key and R. Type a single dot in the run box and press return. An Explorer window will open showing the folders under your username, including Favorites and Desktop. Navigate into the Favorites folder and find the  shortcut you want to put on the desktop. Copy and paste it on to the Desktop, or into the Desktop folder.